# Can not general copy constructor in class template be defaulted?

Tags: c++, templates, language-lawyer, copy-constructor, default-constructor

In the following program struct template `A` has a constructor from `const A<int> &`. For `A<int>` it should be copy-constructor, which can be defaulted:

```
template<typename T>
struct A {
    A() {}
    A(const A<int> &) = default;
};

int main() {
    A<int> a;
}
```

This program is accepted by Clang, but both GCC and MSVC reject it with the error:

```
 error C2610: 'A<T>::A(const A<int> &)': is not a special member function or comparison operator which can be defaulted
note: see reference to class template instantiation 'A<T>' being compiled
```

Demo: https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/Mn6nMbe1x

Which compiler is right here?

Comment: That constructor isn't a copy-constructor, it's a *conversion* constructor, which allows conversions from `A<int>` to `A<T>`.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude: I think that because of the `const &`, clang sees this as copy-ctor. You can also see this by adding `A(A<int> &&) = default;`. I think clang is in the wrong here... But not sure.

Comment: Adding `A<float> a;` all three of them gave the same error. My guess is  `A<int> a;` somehow tricked clang into thinking `A(const A<int> &) = default;` is copy-ctor.

Comment: hmm... maybe clang did not examine the type within the `<>` of each ctor. Because it is not required to specify the typename within the ctors, i.e. `A(const A &)` is the same as `A(const A<T> &`, clang may have skipped this check. Very interesting.

Comment: Can https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4861/temp.res#8.4 and/or https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4861/temp.res#8.5 be used here?